# How to transform pandas dataframe into specific dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
 id      val       label
"a1"    "ab"      "first"
"a1"    "aa"      "second"
"a1"    "ca"      "third"
"b1"    "cc"      "first"
"b1"    "kf"      "second"
"b1"    "ff"      "third"
"c1"    "wer"     "first"
"c1"    "iid"     "second"
"c1"    "ff"      "third"
```

I want to transform it into dictionary wwhere key will be values from columns "id" and values will be dictionaries with keys "label" and values from column "val". so the output must be:

```
{"a1": {"first": {"ab"}, "second": {"aa"}, "third": {"ca"}},
 "b1": {"first": {"cc"}, "second": {"kf"}, "third": {"ff"}},
 "c1": {"first": {"wer"}, "second": {"iid"}, "third": {"ff"}},
}
```

how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recreated your dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
import io


text = """
 id      val       label
"a1"    "ab"      "first"
"a1"    "aa"      "second"
"a1"    "ca"      "third"
"b1"    "cc"      "first"
"b1"    "kf"      "second"
"b1"    "ff"      "third"
"c1"    "wer"     "first"
"c1"    "iid"     "second"
"c1"    "ff"      "third"
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+")
```

Then  I initialized an empty dict

```
reordered_dict = {}
```

then I calculated unique values in `df.id` and iterated over them to populate values:

```
for unique_id in df.id.unique():
    all_matched_items = df.where(df["id"] == unique_id).dropna(axis=0, how="all") # only contains rows where id matches
    items_dict = all_matched_items.set_index("label")["val"].to_dict() # change index to label and export as dict
    for key, val in items_dict.items():
        items_dict[key] = {val} # format asked by you
    reordered_dict[unique_id] = items_dict

print(reordered_dict)
```

The output is then

```
{'a1': {'first': {'ab'}, 'second': {'aa'}, 'third': {'ca'}}, 'b1': {'first': {'cc'}, 'second': {'kf'}, 'third': {'ff'}}, 'c1': {'first': {'wer'}, 'second': {'iid'}, 'third': {'ff'}}}
```

Comment: the output must be ```{"a1": {"first": {"ab"}, "second": {"aa"}, "third": {"ca"}},
 "b1": {"first": {"cc"}, "second": {"kf"}, "third": {"ff"}},
 "c1": {"first": {"wer"}, "second": {"iid"}, "third": {"ff"}},
}```

Comment: @Ir8_mind just updated to match your output

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` on `id` with a lambda function to convert the `label`/`val` pairs into a dict, then `to_dict` on the result to get your desired output:

```py
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:dict(zip(x['label'], x['val']))).to_dict()
```

Output for your sample data:

```
{
 'a1': {'first': 'ab', 'second': 'aa', 'third': 'ca'},
 'b1': {'first': 'cc', 'second': 'kf', 'third': 'ff'},
 'c1': {'first': 'wer', 'second': 'iid', 'third': 'ff'}
}
```

If you want the values in the inner dictionaries to be sets, you can convert them on the fly:

```py
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:dict(zip(x['label'], ({v} for v in x['val'])))).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{
 'a1': {'first': {'ab'}, 'second': {'aa'}, 'third': {'ca'}},
 'b1': {'first': {'cc'}, 'second': {'kf'}, 'third': {'ff'}},
 'c1': {'first': {'wer'}, 'second': {'iid'}, 'third': {'ff'}}
}
```

Comment: the output must be ```{"a1": {"first": {"ab"}, "second": {"aa"}, "third": {"ca"}},
 "b1": {"first": {"cc"}, "second": {"kf"}, "third": {"ff"}},
 "c1": {"first": {"wer"}, "second": {"iid"}, "third": {"ff"}},
}```

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't noticed your inner values were sets. That's a fairly simple change, see my edit.

Comment: If you're already using `zip` it might make more sense to pass a generator instead of using `apply` and building that intermediate Series that's then going to need to be iterated over again `dict(zip(x['label'], ({y} for y in x['val'])))` (I haven't done any testing to confirm if that's actually any faster)

Comment: @HenryEcker interesting point. I suspect what you propose would be faster, if only because it's removing the overhead of the function call. But the point you make about the double iteration is very valid too. I've updated the answer to that code. Thanks